# Track the mail is opened by "To" OR "CC" OR "BCC"

Tags: email, tracking

I am using SMTP for sending emails using PHP.

Is there any way to find out (Track) the mail is opened by "To" or "Cc" or "Bcc"?

Comment: If you need to track by CC or BCC than you need to modify the outgoing email to be different for those three cases. To/CC/BCC is a *sending* decision, not a receiving/reading one.

Comment: Did you find the way except sending separate mails to each of them?

Answer (score -2):

The main way to do it is to include a small 1x1 px image located on your server. Then in the mail request the image url with the unique mail id - and then you can track those image requests and thereby see if the mail has been opened.

It's not a sure-fire way, because of the way various mail systems can block resources/images, especially if the users are more tech-savy; but it's basically the currently 'best' way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

Yes. Currently I am using the same concepts to track the mail is open or not. But I will send the mail with CC and BCC so I need to track the mail is opened by whom (BY To/CC/BCC)?

Comment: Send multiple emails instead of using bcc/cc if that's the case.